# Access AppConfig members

Tags: django, configuration

I want to make my application independent from the project and control branding over the AppConfig. I override the config in my project and every thing seems to work. But how can I access the verbose_name from code? It's not covered in the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs:

```
>>> from django.apps import apps
>>> apps.get_app_config('admin').verbose_name
'Admin'
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/